# Dynamic drop down search only returns one row when selecting books based on publisher

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Before Selection
[image]

After Selection

[image]

PHP CODE To Create Dropdown List
function getPublishers (){

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT bookid, publisher FROM book GROUP BY publisher ORDER BY publisher ASC";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$tot_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
if($tot_rows>0){
    echo "<select name=\"srch_publisher\" id=\"srch_publisher\">\n";
    echo "<option value=\"\">Any Publisher&hellip;</option>\n";
    do{
        echo "<option value=\"".$rows['bookid']."\"";
        getSticky(2, 'srch_publisher', $rows['bookid']);
        echo ">".$rows['publisher']."</option>";
    } while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));
    echo "</select>";
}
mysql_free_result($rs);
```

}

PHP CODE that carries out query based on selection

```
$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT bk.title AS Title, bk.year AS Year, bk.publisher AS Publisher, aut.authorname AS Author 
         FROM book bk 

         JOIN book_category bk_cat 
         ON bk_cat.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN categories cat 
         ON cat.id = bk_cat.category_id

         JOIN books_authors bk_aut 
         ON bk_aut.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN authors aut
         ON aut.id = bk_aut.author_id";

if(isset($_GET['searchInput'])){
$input = $_GET['searchInput'];
$input = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $input);
}
if (isset($input)){

    $getters = array();
    $queries = array();

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
        if (!empty($temp)){
        if (!in_array($key, $getters)){
            $getters[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($getters)) {

        foreach($getters as $key => $value){
            ${$key} = $value;
            switch ($key) {
                case 'searchInput':
                    array_push($queries,"(bk.title LIKE '%$searchInput%' 
                    || bk.description LIKE '%$searchInput%' || bk.isbn LIKE '%$searchInput%' 
                    || bk.keywords LIKE '%$searchInput%' || aut.authorname LIKE '%$searchInput%')");
                break;
                case 'srch_publisher':
                    array_push($queries, "(bk.bookid = $srch_publisher)");
                break;
                case 'srch_author':
                    array_push($queries, "(bk_aut.author_id = $srch_author)");
                break;          
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($queries)){
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        if($i < count($queries)){
            $sql .= $query." AND ";
        } else {
            $sql .= $query;
        }   
        $i++;
    }
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY bk.title  ORDER BY bk.title ASC";

}else{
    $sql .= " GROUP BY bk.title ORDER BY bk.title ASC";
}
```

It shows only one book for the Publishers Bloomsbury, but as you see there are two records in the example. I had this same problem with the authors that it would show two books who had more than one author. Solved using the GROUP BY bk.title. Is the problem to this something similar. Thanks for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$rows['bookid']` in your Publishers select as the value

```
echo "<option value=\"".$rows['bookid']."\"";
    getSticky(2, 'srch_publisher', $rows['bookid']);
    echo ">".$rows['publisher']."</option>";
```

and then in your query you are selecting only that book `bk.bookid = $srch_publisher`

```
case 'srch_publisher':
     array_push($queries, "(bk.bookid = $srch_publisher)");
break;
```

So it is selecting the book by its `bookid`, not by the `publisher`

---

I believe you want use the publisher

```
echo "<option value=\"".$rows['publisher']."\"";
    getSticky(2, 'srch_publisher', $rows['publisher']);
    echo ">".$rows['publisher']."</option>";
```

and search for the publisher

```
case 'srch_publisher':
     array_push($queries, "(bk.publisher = '$srch_publisher')");
break;
```

Comment: thanks for helping, i did what you said but get error "Unknown column 'Bloomsbury' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Are you sure you did `(bk.publisher = '$srch_publisher')` and not `('$srch_publisher' = bk.publisher)`? That error would only happen if you put `$srch_publisher` in the column place of the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: yeah this is weird cause i dont understand why it works (not as desired) when using bookid, but not this      array_push($queries, "(bk.publisher = $srch_publisher)");

Comment: should i ask the forum about the  "Unknown column 'Bloomsbury' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Since `Bloomsbury` is a string, you need to quote it `'$srch_publisher'` - change to `array_push($queries, "(bk.publisher = '$srch_publisher')");`. If unquoted it assumes `Bloomsbury` is a column name, not a column value. (see the quotes in my original answer)